# Laravel eloquent update join with DB::raw() unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm trying to run this update statement, but I get this error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: table2.id`

```
DB::table('table1')
            ->join('table2', 'table1.row_hash', '=', 'table2.row_hash')
            ->where('table1.some_column', '=', 0)
            ->whereNull('table1.reference_no')
            ->update([
                'table1.column_to_update' => 1,
                'table1.column_to_update_2' => 1,
                'table1.column_to_update_3' => 1,
                'table1.reference_no' => DB::raw('table2.id') <--comment this line out and it works.
            ]);
```

If I comment out that one column from the update statement it works. I've tried using various combinations of quotes and backticks inside of the `DB::raw()` statement, but still get the same error. [This post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/migration-and-update-one-table-column-from-another-table-column) seems to indicate that I'm doing this the right way, but it's not cooperating.

How can I update the value of `table1.reference_no` to the value of `table2.id`? I was hoping to accomplish this in one eloquent query as it's a pretty basic SQL statement. Unfortunately I've also tried using just a raw SQL statement, which yielded other errors despite working when running it directly in my mysql client. This is taking entirely too much time for how simple it should be.

Comment: Your are executing your MySQL update behind an obfuscation layer.  If you can, try to print the current (failing) update query to a log file, and see what the syntax problem is.

Comment: Did you mean to put backticks in the `whereNull` call? That's the execution operator, so probably returning null.

Comment: And, this may be obvious, but does `table2` / `quickbooks_transactions` have an `id` column?

Comment: @benJ - Sorry, backticks were unintentional, that wasn't causing the error. I updated the post. table2 does have an ID column..

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled over this.

Putting the values in backticks works. Like this:

`` 'table1.reference_no' => DB::raw('`table2`.`id`') ``